# Spanish for "snowflake" and "snowman" in various regions?

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales

I found myself needing a word for "snowflake" and "snowman" while talking to family.  My nephew was holding a toy snowflake and snowman.

Most spanish-speaking countries live rather close to the equator, so any winter vocabulary would be hypothetical.

Are there Mexican or Puerto Rican snow-related words?  Maybe it snows in some parts of South America in the winter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"snowflake" -> "Copo de nieve"
"snowman"   -> "Muñeco de nieve" (also, but usual only in some countries "Hombre de nieve")

"flake" usually translates as "copo", but depending on the use could also be "hojuela" or "lámina" (as in tobacco flakes)